# Unable to upload images from React to Express, but I can send texts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, react-fullstack

So I have some React (TS) code and I am trying to upload an image from the frontend to the backend, as well as send texts. I am able to send texts (ie, I get Text sent successfully logged to the console) but I am unable to send images.
This is the error message in the console:

Failed to send image to the backend. UploadImg.tsx:27
Selected image file:
File { name: "Screenshot from 2020-09-06 15-20-51.png", lastModified: 1599357052000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1331063, type: "image/png" }

This is my tsx file where I am uploading images:

````
interface UploadImgProps {
  onImageSelected: (imageFile: File | null) => void;
}

const UploadImg: React.FC<UploadImgProps> = ({ onImageSelected }) => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleImageSelected = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
      setSelectedImage(selectedImage);

      try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', selectedImage);

        const response = await fetch('/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Image sent successfully to the backend.');
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to send image to the backend.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      }

      onImageSelected(selectedImage); // Call the prop function
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Please upload the pictures here</h4>
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        onChange={handleImageSelected}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


export default UploadImg;


```server.mjs```

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

// API route for handling feature and image data
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { feature, image } = req.body;
  console.log(`Received data:`, feature);
  res.status(200).send(`Data received successfully.`);
});

// Serve the index.html file from the public directory only for the root URL
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../shoreline_app/public/index.html');
  res.sendFile(indexPath);
});
````

Comment: Could you add what the response look like? Http status code and any possibile error field in the response? From your description of the problem it doesn't look like that it goes to the `catch` block, but the  `else` check.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue using multer. Thanks!